# Check if files were selected on multiupload

Tags: php, file-upload

Ok.. so their is a gallery I'm trying to implement. However, the gallery is NOT OPTIONAL. So I have to check to see if a file was even selected upon upload. However, this is an array of files.

I know, with one file, you would check like so:

```
if($file['error'] !== 4) {
  // file was selected so upload it
}
```

How do I do that with an array of files? Is it automatically an array even if they don't select a file so I loop through it anyways?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `count($_FILES)` gives you the amount of uploaded files (but that number does not indicate whether all of them were sucessful!).

Comment: Yeah I know that.. just not sure if that is the answer I'm looking for. I'm looking for something nice and short like the single upload is.

Comment: You also have to access `$_FILES` in a single upload form. I bet that you're already using `$_FILES[0]` at some point in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_FILES['work']['error'][0] !== 4) {
    echo 'File was uploaded';
} else {
    echo 'File was not uploaded';
}
```

The above code actually works out nicely because if they upload a file, it will still be in the [0] position and the multiselect is automatically put into an array so you can foreach if right after you check that =)